# Where to add jquery "this"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var paircount = 0;
    var $thisSprite = $("#%id% img.imageStyle");

    if ($.browser.msie)
    {
        // I need this only if desaturate png with aplha channel
        $thisSprite = $thisSprite.desaturateImgFix();
    }

    // modified not to desaturate the clone
    $thisSprite.each(function(){
     $(this).addClass("%id%")
      .clone()
      .attr('id', '')
      .addClass('color')
      .hide()
      .insertAfter($(this))
    });

    // desaturate all occourances
    $thisSprite = $thisSprite.desaturate();

    // Need to remove this instance of the desaturated origonal below on hover
    // currently shows both on hover...???????????
    // add events for switch between color/gray versions
    $('.centered_image').bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e){
     $(this).find('img').toggle().toggleClass('color');
    });

});
```

New test at http://www.doobox.co.uk/test/test.html

Kind regards
Gary.

Comment: Please add the content of the desevent function.  I think that might help better explain what's going on.

Comment: That seems like a very inefficient method to switch images. Have you tried to use `toggleClass` (http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/), instead of cloning the image and hiding and showing them?

Comment: @ BBonifield , added the full js file for viewing

Comment: @fudgey , it,s so far the only way i have been able to get a desaturated canvas to switch back on hover. Works great with one image, but as soon as i add another, breaks, as is.

Comment: I don't see a proper problem description in the body of your *question*.

Comment: What is your question? What problem are you having? How have you tried to solve it? What is hidden at the link that you've added (there is no way I'm clicking it at work to see what lurks behind it)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got there in the end thank for the pointers here, helped greatly.

```
 $(window).load(function() {


        var paircount = 0;
        var $thisSprite = $("#%id% img.imageStyle");




        if ($.browser.msie)
        {
          // I need this only if desaturate png with aplha channel
          $thisSprite = $thisSprite.desaturateImgFix();
        }

    // modified not to desaturate the clone
    $thisSprite.each(function(){
     $(this).addClass("%id%pair")
      .clone()
      .attr('id', '')
      .insertAfter($(this))
      .addClass('%id%color')
      .hide()
    });

    // desaturate all occourances
     $thisSprite.desaturate()


     // Need to remove this instance of the desaturated origonal below on hover


    // add events for switch between color/gray versions
    $('.container').bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e){
     $(this).find('.%id%pair').toggle().toggleClass('%id%color');
    });

 });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use JQuery then this is used in following way -

```
$('#id',this).hide();
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a loop and this just seems to confuse things:(use caution if you minify here)

```
 $thisSprite.addClass("pair%id%_" + ++paircount);
```

seems to equate to:

```
$thisSprite.addClass("pair%id%_" + 1);
```

which, if you break it down is:

```
 $thisSprite.addClass("pairsomeIDhere_1");
```

Do you have such a class in your CSS?

```
 var classString = new String($(this).attr('class'));
```

can simply be:

```
 var classString = $(this).attr('class');
```

change:

```
$thisSprite.bind("mouseenter mouseleave", desevent);       
$cloned.bind("mouseenter mouseleave", desevent);
```

to pass the event:

```
$thisSprite.bind("mouseenter mouseleave", desevent(event));       
$cloned.bind("mouseenter mouseleave", desevent(event));
```

Comment: i cant see where the origonal script would have looped over this line, thus incrementing the class:

Comment: $thisSprite.addClass("pair%id%_" + ++paircount);
like you said there does not appear to be a loop. Originally the script was called from the image in the html. i cant call from the image as my image is a system variable %image% with a class of imageStyle thats the only way i can target the image.

Comment: I posted a test page here to demonstrate the current problem: http://www.doobox.co.uk/test/test.html

Answer (score 0):

From looking at your test page, I think the problem is you need to cycle through each image. I tried testing this, but I was having trouble, so sadly this script is untested:

```
$(window).load(function() {

    if ($.browser.msie)
    {
      // You need this only if desaturate png with aplha channel
      $thisSprite = $thisSprite.desaturateImgFix();
    }

    $thisSprite.each(function(){
     $(this).clone()
      .removeAttr('id')
      .addClass('color')
      .hide()
      .insertAfter($(this))
      .desaturate();
    });

    // add events for switch between color/gray versions
    $('.centered_image').bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e){
     $(this).find('img, canvas').toggle().toggleClass('color');
    });
});
```

Comment: i will give that a try, Thank you, i will let you know how i get on.

Comment: Sadly no: demo with this amendment here: http://www.doobox.co.uk/stacks_store/demos/doomap.html

Comment: ps: the js can be found in the line before the closing head tag.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm still not sure why I'm getting a security error when I try to test this, but try modifying the last line to this: `$(this).find('img, canvas').toggle().toggleClass('color');` (edited in the answer above, sorry I forgot the canvas tag was there instead of a second image).

Comment: All working now, a full demo can be seen here: http://www.doobox.co.uk/stacks_store/demos/sprightly.html ... does not seem to be generating any errors.